# C path finder algo stop from some reson i dont know

Tags: c, stack, path-finding

```
void Runner(Node *head, char maze[6][7], int xp, int yp, int maxX , int maxY)
{   
   head = PUSH(head,xp,yp);
   int StackLen = 1;
   Node *RP = head;
   Node *temp = head;
   Node *check = head;
   printf("HERE");
   SHOW(head); `a function that print the Stack`
   printf("HERE");
   
   
   while(maze[xp][yp] != 'E') 
   {   
       printf("HERE");
       if(xp-1 >= 0)
       {
          if (maze[xp-1][yp] != '#')
```

I dont know why it stop after the SHOW(head)
and i doent print the Second "HERE"

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: Your code came incomplete! It will be a pleasure to help you